# Find and replace multiple values within selected cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

I want to run a find and replace on multiple values within a range in excel with values from 2 columns: A with the original word; B with the translation. I already found the VBA code to get this working for 50%, but this code runs it on the whole worskheet.

Ideally I would like to be able to run it on just the range I selected. An added bonus would be if I could also select the lookup range.

This is what I'm using this far. Thanks for your help!

```
Sub abbrev()
            Dim abvtab() As Variant
            Dim ltsheet As Worksheet
            Dim datasheet As Worksheet
            Dim lt As Range

            'Change Lookup to the sheet name with your lookup table.
            Set ltsheet = Sheets("Lookup")

            'Change Data to the sheet name with your data.
            Set datasheet = Sheets("Data")

            'Change A2 to the top left cell (not the header) in your lookup table.
            'Change B2 to top right cell.
            Set lt = ltsheet.Range("A1", ltsheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown))

            abvtab = lt

            For i = 1 To UBound(abvtab)
                datasheet.Cells.Replace What:=abvtab(i, 1), Replacement:=abvtab(i, 2), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False
            Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Excel Multi Replace

1. Open your VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and paste the below macro anywhere
2. Set up a two-column lookup range: 1st column is the value to search for,
   2nd the value to replace
3. **Select** your input range where values should be replaced like shown in the 1st picture
4. Execute the macro (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>).

The macro asks where your Lookup range is. First the sheet name, then the Lookup range address. Enter only the first column e.g `A1:A2` for the example below.

That's it. Now the macro begins to iterate through all replace rules and applies them like a
normal Excel Search & Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) onto your selected input range.

```
Input range            Replace rules               Input range after macro
```

[image][image] [image]

```
Sub MultiReplace()
On Error GoTo errorcatch
Dim arrRules() As Variant

    strSheet = InputBox("Enter sheet name where your replace rules are", _
        "Sheet name", "Sheet1")
    strRules = InputBox("Enter address of replaces rules." & vbNewLine & _
        "But only the first column!", "Address", "A1:A100")

    Set rngCol1 = Sheets(strSheet).Range(strRules)
    Set rngCol2 = rngCol1.Offset(0, 1)
    arrRules = Application.Union(rngCol1, rngCol2)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrRules)
        Selection.Replace What:=arrRules(i, 1), Replacement:=arrRules(i, 2), _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True
    Next i

errorcatch:
End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range :(

Comment: In fact, it will only replace A1 for me. Also, if you replace the lookup range to: `A1:A3`, it will return the runtime error.

Comment: The find and replace should replace all found values in each cell in the range I provide. Right now, it only works on call A1 for me... . Yes, that's fine. Thanks!

Comment: See my edit. In my test scenario I selected `A1:A4` on the first sheet and executed the macro. (lookup sheet name was `Lookup` and Lookup range was `A1:A3`). For me its working perfectly. It replaces everything.

Comment: Great scripts!. For anyone need to replace parts of text, just change `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart`