# How can I find and replace multiple values within selected cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, find-and-replace

I want to run a find and replace on multiple values within a range in excel with values from 2 columns: A with the original string; B with the replacement string. I already found a macro that is somewhat working (thanks nixda), but cannot handle the dashes in between some of the longer values in the original string.

Ideally I would like to be able to run it on just the range I selected. An added bonus would be if I could also select the lookup range.

Below is sample values of the original and replacement value columns:

Original values column:

```
T1-D7-F2-F3-    
T1-D7-F2-F3-C33    
U4 U5 Q2 Q4    
U3-Q7.U1    
R42-43-22-23-
```

Replacement Values column:

```
T1,D7,F2,F3    
T1,D7,F2,F3,C33    
U4,U5,Q2,Q4    
U3,Q7,U1    
R42,R43,R22,R23
```

#### Update in response to Gary's Student' answer

Values in "data" tab, column A:

```
1000PF CAP
4 SCREWS
D21 D22 - 709
D4-U3-RV3-Q2-U3
D7 - 00004224
D7 - 0004224
D7 - 004224
D7-F2-C33-F3-U6
D7-F3-J1
END PLATE
END PLATES
F2 F3 - 219
F2-F3-T1
Q11-Q3-J2-J9-
Q2 Q10 U12
Q2 Q3 Q10 Q11
Q2 Q3 Q11 Q10
Q2- Q4- U4- U5
Q2-Q5-Q8-Q10
Q3-Q11.R95
Q5-C10-C35
Q5-C19
```

Values in "tabl" tab, column A will be same as above

Values in "tabl" tab, column B (replacement values):

```
1000PF_CAP
4SCREWS
D21,D22,000709
D4,U3,RV3,Q2,U3
D7,004224
D7,004224
D7,004224
D7,F2,C33,F3,U6
D7,F3,J1
END_PLATE(S)
END_PLATE(S)
F2,F3,000219
F2,F3,T1
Q11,Q3,J2,J9
Q2,Q10,U12
Q2,Q3,Q10,Q11
Q2,Q3,Q11,Q10
Q2,Q4,U4,U5
Q2-Q5-Q8-Q10
Q3,Q11,R95
Q5,C10,C35
Q5,C19
```

After I run the macro, I get the following results, instead of what I expect:

```
1000PF_CAP CAP
4SCREW(S)S
D21,D22 - 709
D4,U3,RV3-Q2-U3
D700004224
D70004224
D7004224
D7,F2-C33-F3-U6
D7,F3-J1
END_PLATE(S)
END_PLATE(S)S
F2,F3 - 219
F2,F3-T1
Q11-Q3-J2,J9-
Q2,Q10 U12
Q2 Q3 Q10,Q11
Q2,Q3,Q11 Q10
Q2,Q4- U4,U5
Q2-Q5Q8-Q10
Q3,Q11.R95
Q5C10,C35
Q5C19
```

Any ideas?

---

**Edit**

After running [this macro](https://superuser.com/a/620498/50173) to replace values, I have trouble with the following values:

Left column below = Lookup columns A and B have same values (should not change, except for R 3 should become R3).

Right column below = Result after running the macro.

```
Q?  Q?
Q1  Q?
Q2  Q?
Q3  Q?
Q4  Q?
Q5  Q?
Q6  Q?
Q7  Q?
Q8  Q?
Q9  Q?
QR? QR?
R 3 R?
R?  R?
R0  R?
R1  R?
R2  R?
R3  R?
R4  R?
R5  R?
R6  R?
R7  R?
R8  R?
R9  R?
RE  R?
RV  R?
```

Comment: So you to change the three characters {<space> - .} all to commas??

Comment: Well, not exactly. For example, the original values might be missing the letter R (see last row of example above), and they are corrected (letter R included) in the replacement values.

Comment: The replacement value might be completely different than the original value. Every time the original value is found in the spreadsheet, it should be substituted with its corresponding replacement value from the "lookout" tab.

Comment: @Daniel Please test my [fixed code](http://superuser.com/a/620498/50173). I made a small mistake with xlPart and xlWhole

Comment: @nixda I did test it and it did no replacements? Am I doing something wrong? My tabs are named "data" and "lookup".

Comment: @nixda I tried it again (had to select my data first) and it works PERFECTLY! Thanks a lot nixda! After this macro step I need to apply two further operations to get to the point when my data will be usable though. First, I need to manually replace all commas with a "Alt+010". Then, I have a macro that separates the multiple value cells into separate records. I was wondering if there is a way to COMBINE all these steps into ONE macro. (I know, it's too much to ask for). THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: @Daniel Oh, that's a little bit too much to ask for it =) This site isn't there for writing everyones code. It's about trying it yourself, getting stuck somewhere and come back with a problem you can't solve yourself. Usually we want to see that you at least have tried it on your own. After that, you will get good answers ;)

Comment: Fair enough! Your macro will save me a lot of time. I guess I will start learning VBA, seems to be really useful. See you around.

Comment: @nixda It's me again. Happy Hallpween btw. I used the macro for a huge spreadsheet (~100,000 rows) with a lookup table of ~2,600 rows! It works prefectly! I just found one type of entries that cannot be replaced correctly. If I have "Q?" in the lookup range that does not change, all "Q1" to "Q9" values get replaced by "Q?". Q11, Q12, etc do not have that problem. Same with "R?". Any thoughts? I might just delete the Q?=Q? and R?=R? entries in columns A and B of the lookup table and see if it will do the trick.

Comment: @Daniel `?` or `*` are [wildcard characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee440632(v=office.12).aspx). This will mess up the macro. Try to get rid of them before using the macro. Usually I replace them with a very unique string like `? » $$$` and after the macro has done its job i revert that with `$$$ » ?`

Comment: Yes, I removed the entries containing "?" and now it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small sample macro.  The translation table is in a tab called "tabl" and the data to be edited is in a tab called "data":

```
Sub ChangeValues()
    Dim N As Long, L As Long
    Dim rLook As Range
    Sheets("tabl").Select
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    aryA = Range("A1:A" & N)
    aryB = Range("B1:B" & N)
    Sheets("data").Select
    Set rLook = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select replacement range", Type:=8)
    For L = 1 To N
        rLook.Replace aryA(L, 1), aryB(L, 1)
    Next L
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the macro! It does what the macro that I had before was doing - some values were replaced ok, some - not. How can I attach a sample spreadsheet here to show what I mean?

Comment: Not possible in this forum

Comment: Can I send a sample spreadsheet by e-mail?

Comment: @Daniel Just upload it at [ge.tt](http://ge.tt/) and [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/659904/edit) the link into your question. You mentioned me, can you link me the original question? Maybe I can fix that code

Comment: @nixda I saw your solution for a similar problem here: http://superuser.com/questions/620484/find-and-replace-multiple-values-within-selected-cells

Comment: @nixda Thanks for the ge.tt upload site info! Here is the link: http://ge.tt/1pTvoPv/v/0?c

Answer (score 0):

If you install the [RegEx Find/Replace addon](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php), you can use the following regular expressions to accomplish this, and I've tested it out.  It works.

```
Find:           \s*[-.]\s*
Replacement:    ,
Find:           \s+(?!$)
Replacement:    _
```

Comment: I just noticed that you have a dash at the end of one of the lines, and that ends up indiscriminately replaced as well.  You might want to run one more RegEx find/replace.  Find `,$` and replace with nothing.  That will get rid of any dangling commas like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks promising! Will give it a try ASAP. The macro that nixda provided works perfectly, I just found one type of entries that cannot be replaced correctly. If I have "Q?" in the lookup range, all "Q1" to "Q9" values get replaced by "Q?". Q11, Q12, etc do not have that problem. Same with "R?". Hope RegEx will be able to take care of that.