# Excel Macro looping

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

I used [this macro](https://superuser.com/a/620498/275436) and it worked fine, but I needed a little bit more.

I had to change `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart` and add the color formatting.  Now, when I select a column, the Macro appears to run through the column three times before it finishes, so it's making triplicate replacements.

Original field is: 7555 embedded in text.  Reference spreadsheet has two columns, A has 7555, B has 77555.  Once the Macro finishes, many of the numbers are now 777555, but some are correct.  Odd!

Can anyone assist with editing this macro to stop it from looping?

```
Sub MultiReplace()
On Error GoTo errorcatch
Dim arrRules() As Variant

    Set rngCol1 = Sheets(strSheet).Range(strRules)
    Set rngCol2 = rngCol1.Offset(0, 1)
    arrRules = Application.Union(rngCol1, rngCol2)

    ' Set the CellFormat object to replace with green.
    With Application
        .ReplaceFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    End With

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrRules)
        Selection.Replace What:=arrRules(i, 1), Replacement:=arrRules(i, 2), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    Next i

errorcatch:
End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot confirm this behavior with [my sample workbook](http://ge.tt/4cfQVS01/v/0) for your question. Maybe I can have a look at a sample workbook of yours?

Comment: Are you calling this macro from a workbook event? If not, how is it getting called?

Comment: Try printing out the UBound(arrRules) to see if it is the number you would expect.