# Excel replace value in a column using a pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I should start by saying that I am probably over complicating this. I have a file that contains certain column values that are considered confidential data. In most cases, they would be removed from any data set that would be shared or analyzed. However a request was submitted to generate a data set that would allow, among many other things, the user to compare the number of distinct ID's compared to the total number of entries. So across something like 140,000 records, I have to replace three columns that are considered protected.

The challenge I am facing is in how to mask a 22 character alphanumeric ID in such a way that it's no longer identifying, but also maintains some semblance of relationship between duplicate entries that might exist.

The other two columns seems to have converted without incident after adapting [an answer I found on here](https://superuser.com/questions/620484/find-and-replace-multiple-values-within-selected-cells) to work with the requirements. The longer ID however for some reason lost integrity when the same function was pointed at it. I tried to restrict the number of characters I was changing at once, however that didn't seem to solve my problem.

The end result that I'm looking for, or have been told I have to produce is just the raw data set. I can't do the grouping of the data for the end user, they have to receive it such that each row accounts for one record, and then whatever analysis they wanted to complete from there.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do than the link above/a really large find and replace?

---

Addition:
Since I can't actually post the data that I'm looking to apply this to, I thought I should try to replicate it somehow to aid in any potential answers that might be out there.

Suppose I have these IDs:

> ID                           VTC            DTE
>
> A8894512374516347852001      110            8/9/2016
>
> J7763473861247762551000      1180           8/9/2016
>
> Q4523732167498765146000      375            8/9/2016
>
> T6348761321688873431001      703            8/9/2016
>
> H6676314656873346615001      375            8/9/2016
>
> A8894512374516347852001      5091           8/9/2016
>
> T6348761321688873431001      5091           8/9/2016
>
> S8897613515646873143168      375            8/9/2016

Now, what I was hoping to find was a way to take instances, like the records that started with "A889" and ensure they ended up together, but not the others. The issue is that with the number of records (it's up to 170,000), the number of distinct ID numbers is probably close to 120,000 that would have to be accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data like:

[image]

But the age group is considered confidential.  This little macro:

```
Sub HideSensitiveFactor()
    ary = Array("10 - 19", "20 - 29", "30 - 39", "40 - 69", "70 - 200")
    bry = Array("grp1", "grp2", "grp3", "grp4", "grp5")
    Dim rng As Range, i As Long
    Set rng = Range("B:B")

    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        rng.Replace what:=ary(i), replacement:=bry(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

So the fact that the column represents **age groups** is hidden, but any statistically groupings will be retained.

Comment: This is a great solution, and I can certainly use it in other places. That said, I think it would lead to over generalization of the type of data that I'm looking at currently. Let me amend the question a little bit more.

Comment: @dramerus ......................Okay ......................

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm complicated the entire thing too much @Gary's Student? The solution you provided would certainly allow me to group the IDs together, the problem is that the array would be quite large when looking at this type of data. Think of this ID more like an SSN or something like that, but an ID that could have multiple records attached to it. In this case, I need to be able to ensure that each of those records keeps its relationship to the others.

Comment: @dramerus  Now I understand...............will can build a collection of **unique IDs** and a translate table....................I will update later.